# When signing into Magento admin, it initially allows me to sign in, but when I click any link in the admin, it boots me out. Why?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

Basically whenever I try to login to the Magento admin, it initially works fine, but as soon as I click on a link, it boots me out. When I log back in, everything works fine.

There's also some weird behavior in that I have to clear the cache anytime I need to run a sales report (or any other report.)